# Enzyme-Jest React, I cannot figure out why my props are not updating after simulating this 'change' event. Thank you

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a controlled form component with Enzyme-Jest.  I have simulated a 'change' event which should call my handleFormChange method which is passed down as a prop from parent.  When I check the props for the ImproveListing component, they do not update/change after I simulate this event.  Thanks

```
describe('<ImproveListing /> Form', () => {
    let improveListing;
    let app;
    let instance;

    beforeEach(() => {
      app = mount(<Attraction />);
      instance = app.instance();
      improveListing = mount(<ImproveListing />);
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      app.unmount();
      improveListing.unmount();
    });

test('it should update form data with state', () => {
        improveListing.setProps({ clicked: true });
        const input = improveListing.find('input').first();
        input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test', name: 'description' } });
        const changedInput = improveListing.find('input').first();
        expect(changedInput.props().value).toEqual('test');
      });
```

this is the console output after running the test

```
<Overview /> › <ImproveListing /> Form › HandleFormChange › it should update form data with state

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "test"
    Received: ""

      82 |         // improveListing.setProps({ form: { description: 'Test' } });
      83 |         const changedInput = improveListing.find('input').first();
    > 84 |         expect(changedInput.props().value).toEqual('test');
         |                                            ^
      85 |       });
      86 |     });
      87 |   });
```

```
//ImproveListing.js

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ImproveListing = ({ clicked, form, handleFormChange, handleClick }) => (

  <div className="improveListing">
    {clicked ? (
      <form className="improve" onSubmit={() => {}}>

        <input name="description" placeholder="description" type="text" value={form.description} onChange={handleFormChange} />

      </form>
    ) : <div onClick={handleClick}>Improve This Listing</div>}
  </div>
);

//Overview.js (parent to ImproveListing)

const Overview = ({ overview, form, handleFormChange, clicked, handleClick }) => (

  <div className="overview">
    <ImproveListing
      form={form}
      handleFormChange={handleFormChange}
      clicked={clicked}
      handleClick={handleClick}
    />
  </div>
);

//attraction.js (parent to overview)

export default class Attraction extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: null,
      likeHover: false,
      form: {
        description: '',
        isOpen: false,
        suggestedDuration: 0,
        address: '',
      },
      clickImproved: false,
    };
    this.updateHeartHover = this.updateHeartHover.bind(this);
    this.handleFormChange = this.handleFormChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

 handleFormChange(e) {
    const { form } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      form: {
        ...form,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      },
    });
  }

render() {
    const {
      current, likeHover, form, clickImproved,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {current ? (
          <div className="attraction">
          
            <Overview
              overview={current.overview}
              form={form}
              clicked={clickImproved}
              handleClick={this.handleClick}
              handleFormChange={this.handleFormChange}
            />
           
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `improveListing.update()` after simulate the change handler.

Comment: I tried this, it seems like it is still receiving an empty string. Thanks

Comment: Could you please check your change event is simulating ?

Answer (score 0):

This test passes.

```
test('it should call handleFormChange when there is a change', () => {
        improveListing.setProps({ clicked: true });
        const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleFormChange');
        improveListing.setProps({ handleFormChange: instance.handleFormChange });
        const input = improveListing.find('input').first();
        input.simulate('change');
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      });
```